# Inequality $\frac{xy+z}{x+yz}+\frac{yz+x}{y+zx}+\frac{zx+y}{z+xy}-\frac{x+y+z}{3}\leq 1$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

For $x,y,z \in [2,\infty)$, prove that

$\frac{xy+z}{x+yz}+\frac{yz+x}{y+zx}+\frac{zx+y}{z+xy}-\frac{x+y+z}{3}\leq  1$

I tried to group the terms and prove that $\frac{xy+z}{x+yz} - \frac{y}{3}\leq \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Unfortunately, your strategy does not work: try $x = 2, y = 2, z = 5$ for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using the **lemma**:if $a,b\ge 2$ then $ab\ge a+b$

$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{xy+z}{x+\color{red}{yz}}-\sum \frac{x}{3}$$ $$\le \sum_{cyc} \frac{xy+z}{x+\color{red}{y+z}}-\sum\frac{x}{3}=1-\dfrac{1}{6}\Big( \dfrac{{(x-y)}^2+{(y-z)}^2+{(z-x)}^2}{x+y+z}\Big)\le 1$$

Comment: This is a beautiful solution!

Comment: @W.Wongcharoenbhorn thanks any way thanks  for pointing mistake in calculuation.I however think its 1/3 rather than 1/6

Comment: Isn't it $1/6$? as you have $(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2=2(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)$.

Comment: @W.Wongcharoenbhorn yes of course!thanks